# Writing Logs/results or generating reports using Selenium C# API

Tags: nunit, selenium

I am testing the web application using Selenium RC. All things works fine and I have written many test cases and executing these test cases using Nunit.

Now the hurdle that I am facing is how to keep track of failures or how to generate the Reports?

Please advice which could be best way to capture this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're using NUnit you'll want to use NUnits reporting facilities. If the GUI runner is enough, that's great. But if you're running from the command line, or NAnt, you'll want to use the XML output take a look at the [NAnt documentation](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=consoleCommandLine&r=2.2) for more information.

If you're using Nant you'll want to look at [NUnit2Report](http://nunit2report.sourceforge.net/NUnit2Report.Examples.html). It's nolonger maintained, but it may suit your needs. Alternatively, you could extract it's XSLT files and apply it against the XML output.

Selenium itself doesn't have report because it is only a library used by many different languages.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else happening randomly into this question, the 'nunit2report' task is now available in NAntContrib.

[NantContrib Nunit2report task](http://nantcontrib.sourceforge.net/release/0.91/help/tasks/nunit2report.html)